# Guarded thread C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I'm trying to create a "guarded_thread", but I receive an error 'operator=' is a private member of 'std::__1::thread'. Here is my code:

```
struct guarded_thread : std::thread{
    using std::thread::thread;
    using std::thread::operator=;
    ~guarded_thread(){if(joinable())join();}
};
```

A function did the work, but I want to know how to create it the other way

```
void Guarded_thread(std::thread &Thread){
    if (Thread.joinable()) {
        Thread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mre] and explain what your code is supposed to do. Isn't the error fairly self explanatory? You're trying to use the assignment operator which is private on `std::thread`

Comment: note that C++20 has `std::jthread` and that (publicly) inheriting from std types isnt always the best idea.

Comment: `std::thread` cannot be copied, and so can't any classes inheriting from it. But you could have a simple `std::thread` member variable for your class, instead of inheriting.

Comment: the code doesn't also take in account that thread can be running indefinitely and be running when destructor is called. jthread is requested to stop from destructor, which is a feature of jthread.

Answer (score 1):

`std::thread`s destructor is not virtual. Hence, you won't get to use your `guarded_thread` polymorphically and there is little benefit of inheritance compared to making the thread a member. `std::thread` cannot be copied, thats basically what the error says, so `guarded_thread` cannot be copied as well. Though, it can be moved:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

struct guarded_thread {
    std::thread t;
    ~guarded_thread() {
        if(t.joinable()) {
            t.join();
        }
    }
};

void foo(guarded_thread&& t) {}

int main() {
    foo(guarded_thread{ std::thread{ [](){ std::cout << "hello world"; }}});
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vjdfdozbK)

PS: `std::thread` not joining in its destructor was a surprise for many, and maybe also driven by that C++20 introduced `std::jthread`. As pointed out in a comment by Swift, `std::jthread`s destructor also `request_stop()`s the thread before joining it, while `guarded_thread` blocks forever when the thread runs infinitely.